# How to use the information in XMLHttpRequest.send(string)

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I'm sending a POST request with a string in the `.send()` part which is `"id=jeff&command=test"`.

How do I parse and use these values in Java via the `HttpServletRequest` object?

I've tried changing the content type to `text/html` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
My java server is embedded jetty btw.

```
var text = form.command.value;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
            xmlhttp.responseText
          }
        }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", 'go', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("id=jeff&command=" + text);
```

here's my Java code

```
public class GoHandler extends HttpServlet 
{
Commands c = Commands.getInstance();
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    String str = "";
    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    String p = request.getParameter("id");
    String input = request.getParameter("command"); 
    System.out.print(p);
```

here is my output when I make the request from a browser

id=jeff&command=test (this is from the buffered reader)

null (this is from my String p which should be the id)

here's Chrome's toolkit thing..

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/go
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:20
Content-Type:application/xml
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4
Request Payload
id=jeff&command=test
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:66
Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8
Server:Jetty(8.1.7.v20120910)
```

my response from the server

```
{"flavor":"You are in the goHandler"}
```

Comment: Show your Ajax call so we can make sure the request is set up correctly.

Comment: On server side, what does `httpServletRequest.getParameter("id")` return?

Comment: String p = request.getParameter("id"); 
System.out.print(p); this print null

Comment: Why don't you use standard JavaScript libraries like jQuery?! :) These kinda issues are common in native JS and the frameworks provide easy way to address these also the cross browser issues. Say, your above JS code won't work in old IE browsers (bcoz XMLHttpRequest is not there).

Comment: My issue isn't with javascript its with the server getting the properties the way its supposed to (using getPeoperty(string) ) the post requests will be sent from android code in the end so javascript and browsers won't be an issue. I'm just using it to test server requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it as buffered reader. This will give full string. The you can parse it manually. If your separator is "\n" then,

```
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
  jb.append(str);
```

Edit:

Can you try one/both of these http headers?! Here is your updated code.

```
var text = form.command.value;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
    }
var params = "id=jeff&command=" + encodeURIComponent(text);
xmlhttp.open("POST", "go", true);
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Using encodeURIComponent() to convert the URI into valid ASCII.

Updated the JavsScript since the default content-type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" so removed it. Now try to access all your parameters in the servlet.

Comment: That works. But is there no built in way of getting these values?

Comment: I added the code to my request. My output hasn't changed though.

Comment: Chrome's debug tools now says that it's form data but in my program my strings are still null

Comment: Updated the above answer. Pls check.

Answer (score 2):

"That works. But is there no built in way of getting these values?"

Don't read input stream to get parameter because once you read input stream you reached at the end of input stream and native method `getParameter()` does not reset input stream  that's why it returns null.
use `getParameter()` directly to get values.

Use either `InputStream` or `getParameter()` don't use both

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException
{`    `

String p=request.getParameter("id");
String input=request.getParameter("command");
System.out.println(p);
```